# How to prevent deferred execution from blowing up at the wrong time?

Tags: c#

Consider the following class OperationResult and the following snippet of code that leverages it.
The idea was to wrap a possible exception being thrown inside the task (Func) that is provided.
But because the return object is an IEnumerable that wasn't enumerated, the wrapper object thinks everything went according to plan. Later when someone executes ToList() on the data, the exception gets thrown and goes potentially unhandled.

Is there a strategy to dealing with this sort of situation?

Keep in mind this is just example code and the point isn't to create an OperationResult class.
Forcing the data to get enumerated only works for this particular example and there may be other situations where deferred execution gets passed in the task.
I'm looking for something that works in .net framework 4.8 but I'd be interested even if it could only work in .net core.

```
public class OperationResult<T>
{
    public T Data { get; }
    public Exception OperationException  { get; }
    
    private OperationResult(T data, Exception operationException)
    {
        Data = data;
        OperationException = operationException;
    }
    
    public static OperationResult<T> Try(Func<T> task)
    {
        try
        {
            return new OperationResult<T>(task(), null);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return new OperationResult<T>(default(T), ex);
        }
    }   
}
```

```
var result = OperationResult<IEnumerable<Tuple<int, string>>>.Try(() =>
{
    var ids = new int[] { 19, 3, 43, 17, 23 };
    return ids.Select<int, Tuple<int, string>>(id => throw new NotImplementedException());
});
```

Comment: You may use [.Take(N)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netcore-3.1) from `LINQ` to limit `IEnumerable` to not more than first `N` items

Comment: If I was going to enumerate, I'd use Count(). But I was hoping for a pattern designed to deal with class of problem and not something specific for IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a general solution, given you can't put a constraint on the T parameter to rule out 'lazy' types. `IEnumerable` is the most obvious here, but `Task` behaves in a similar way, as does any type that has a property that needs to be accessed before it is fully evaluated.

But - this doesn't mean you can't use specific strategies for well-known types. Instead of just capturing the result of the `take()` function, you can delegate to a set of handlers to evaluate it as much as you want to, to firm it up. The more handlers the better.

The challenge is in being able to do this nicely in the presence of generic parameters (unavoidable when the main type you're worried about is `IEnumerable<T>`).

Luckily there is the very excellent dynamic dispatch pattern:

```cs
public Result<A> Try(Func<A> task) {
  try {
    var val = Evaluate((dynamic)task()); //DLR magic here - will bind to most specific method
    return new Result<A>(val);
  }
  catch(...) {
    ...
  }
}

private IEnumerable<B> Evaluate<B>(IEnumerable<B> items)
  => items.ToArray();

//handlers for other types you care about here...

private object Evaluate(object obj) //catch all default
  => obj;
```